# service command does not work in centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, sysvinit

I used to use `service` command for restarting, reloading, and checking status of service on centos 6.5 like below:

`$ sudo service nginx restart                  OK`
`$ sudo service nginx status                   OK`

But, in CentOS 7 I get this notice for doing the same thing.

```
[root@admin ~]# service nginx restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  nginx.service
[root@admin ~]#
```

**Question:** How do I start nginx service in Centos7.5?

Answer (score 7):

`service` command doesn't work in CentOS 7 any more. Redhat based OS migrated to Systemd from SysVinit system.

You have to use `systemctl start nginx.service`

For sysVinit to systemd cheatsheet visit following link:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet

Comment: Weird. It does work with just `systemctl start nginx` but it never shows the status, or OK message.

Comment: For RHEL 7, the `systemctl` command replaces `service` and `chkconfig`, however, you can still use the `service` and `chkconfig` commands to start/stop and enable/disable services, respectively.